# encoding UTF-8 not auto detected in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, utf

At https://demo.phppointofsale.com/ the encoding in head of page is utf-8, the response headers are utf-8; but it still auto detects as Windows-1252 in Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me, it is currently detects as UTF-8.